Перестановка списка с ключами местами каждый раз при запуске
Как можно реализовать чтобы список читался рандомно? Чтобы если вписано в переменную l = 60 то суммировало из списка эти 60 по разному а не так чтобы каждый раз выводило одно и тоже.
Задумано сделать программу в которой можно ввести кол-во бензина и она просчитает сколько километров при X расходе. Рассчитав кол-во километров выводит населения, подходящие суммарно по километражу для того чтобы не считать и не думать что вписать в путевой лист
from itertools import combinations
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io


FACK = {60:'Тлюстен 60 км', 52:'Тугургой 52 км', 36:'Казазов 36 км',
        50:'Красненский 50 км', 28:'Пчегатлукай 28 км', 30:'Адыгейск 30 км', 26:'Вочепший 26 км', 12:'Пшикуйхабль 12 км',
        10:'Нечерезии 10 км', 8:'Нешукай 8 км', 42:'Кунчукохабль 42 км, через аулы', 56:'Кунчукохабль 56 км через трассу',
        27:'Тауйхабль 27 км', 19:'Джиджихабль 19 км', 17:'Шевченко 17 км', 37:'Габукай 37 км', 4:'тест', 33:'тест'}


l = 60 # тут вводим километры

Array = {}

f = io.StringIO()

for i in combinations(FACK, 2):# тут вписываем количество чисел на которые будет суммироваться
    if sum(i) == l:
        with redirect_stdout(f):# перехват выводимого значения на print()
            print(*i)
            break

Array = s = f.getvalue()# получает строковые значения выводимые print()'ом

ar = Array[0]
ar += Array[1]
arint = int(ar)# переабразовываем строковый в целочисленное

ar2 = Array[3]
ar2 += Array[4]
arint2 = int(ar2)

print(FACK[arint], FACK[arint2])




Тугургой 52 км Нешукай 8 км

Process finished with exit code 0


random.shuffle не подходит?

В Бейсике не было функции, которая число переводила в строковую форму. А оператор печати был. Ушлые программисты чтобы не писать форматирование самим, открывали файл, печатали число в нужном формате, переоткрывали файл на чтение и получали строку, которую можно было использовать дальше. Времени на это уходило уйма, особенно на больших таблицах. Это было в прошлом веке. В этом веке я не ожидал что кто-то будет извлекать данные через файловый поток. Моё ошеломление!

ТС, расскажите какую задачу вы решаете. Словами. Добавьте в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Жесть, только увидел redirect_stdout. Просто зачем?

@insolor нет, пробовал с shuffle перепробовал, нахожу много ответов но у меня получается так, что print(FACK[arint], FACK[arint2]) выводит разные значение, в обход 18 строки for i in combinations(FACK, 2):* то есть игнорируется значение 60 и просто показывает рандомно.

@insolor combinations не возвращает ничего кроме как печати, вот и решил перехватить) да колхоз но  я еще зеленый(учусь)

Это не combinations ничего не возвращает, кроме печати, это вы вместо того, чтобы сразу в Array (или куда-то еще) результат добавить, зачем-то его печатаете.

@insolor результат проходящий после with redirect_stdout(f) никчему не смог привязать, из за чего и затеял этот колхоз

Вот вместо print можно подставить Array = s = " ".join(str(item) for item in i), и логика не изменится (redirect_stdout соответственно убрать). Но лучше убрать join и конвертацию в строки, и просто i как есть присваивать.

Поддержим дерзость этого вопроса информационными технологиями! Даёшь рекурсивный поиск в помощь логистике!

Во-первых словарь не позволяет иметь несколько пунктов на одном расстоянии. Сделаем список пар (расстояние, название).
Во-вторых, кто сказал что в маршруте должно быть только два пункта? Сделаем несколько. Поиск маршрута будет рекурсивный: есть слагаемые, требуется набрать сумму.
Перед поиском список расстояний случайно перемешивается.
import random


def routes(legs, target):

    def search(i, target, route):
        if i == len(legs):
            if target == 0:
                yield tuple(route)
        else:
            yield from search(i + 1, target, route)
            d, n = legs[i]
            if d <= target:
                route.append(n)
                yield from search(i + 1, target - d, route)
                route.pop()

    return search(0, target, [])

        
def main():
    legs = (
        (60, 'Тлюстен 60 км'),
        (52, 'Тугургой 52 км'),
        (36, 'Казазов 36 км'),
        (50, 'Красненский 50 км'),
        (28, 'Пчегатлукай 28 км'),
        (30, 'Адыгейск 30 км'),
        (26, 'Вочепший 26 км'),
        (12, 'Пшикуйхабль 12 км'),
        (10, 'Нечерезии 10 км'),
        ( 8, 'Нешукай 8 км'),
        (42, 'Кунчукохабль 42 км, через аулы'),
        (56, 'Кунчукохабль 56 км через трассу'),
        (27, 'Тауйхабль 27 км'),
        (19, 'Джиджихабль 19 км'),
        (17, 'Шевченко 17 км'),
        (37, 'Габукай 37 км'),
        ( 4, 'тест'),
        (33, 'тест')
    )

    dist = int(input())
    legs_list = list(legs)
    random.shuffle(legs_list)
    for r in routes(legs_list, dist):
        print(', '.join(r))


main()


$ echo 60 | python routes.py
Тлюстен 60 км
Тугургой 52 км, Нешукай 8 км
Нечерезии 10 км, Красненский 50 км
Нечерезии 10 км, Кунчукохабль 42 км, через аулы, Нешукай 8 км
Адыгейск 30 км, Нечерезии 10 км, Нешукай 8 км, Пшикуйхабль 12 км
Тауйхабль 27 км, тест
Шевченко 17 км, Нечерезии 10 км, тест
Джиджихабль 19 км, тест, Нешукай 8 км
тест, Кунчукохабль 56 км через трассу
тест, Нечерезии 10 км, Нешукай 8 км, Пшикуйхабль 12 км, Вочепший 26 км
тест, Адыгейск 30 км, Вочепший 26 км
тест, Шевченко 17 км, Тауйхабль 27 км, Пшикуйхабль 12 км
тест, Казазов 36 км, Нешукай 8 км, Пшикуйхабль 12 км
тест, Джиджихабль 19 км, Тауйхабль 27 км, Нечерезии 10 км
тест, Джиджихабль 19 км, Шевченко 17 км, Нешукай 8 км, Пшикуйхабль 12 км
тест, Джиджихабль 19 км, Габукай 37 км

$ echo 60 | python routes.py
Нешукай 8 км, Адыгейск 30 км, Пшикуйхабль 12 км, Нечерезии 10 км
Нешукай 8 км, Кунчукохабль 42 км, через аулы, Нечерезии 10 км
Тугургой 52 км, Нешукай 8 км
тест, Джиджихабль 19 км, Габукай 37 км
тест, Нешукай 8 км, Пшикуйхабль 12 км, Казазов 36 км
тест, Нешукай 8 км, Джиджихабль 19 км, Шевченко 17 км, Пшикуйхабль 12 км
тест, Тауйхабль 27 км, Шевченко 17 км, Пшикуйхабль 12 км
тест, Тауйхабль 27 км, Джиджихабль 19 км, Нечерезии 10 км
Вочепший 26 км, тест, Адыгейск 30 км
Вочепший 26 км, тест, Нешукай 8 км, Пшикуйхабль 12 км, Нечерезии 10 км
Красненский 50 км, Нечерезии 10 км
Кунчукохабль 56 км через трассу, тест
тест, Шевченко 17 км, Нечерезии 10 км
тест, Нешукай 8 км, Джиджихабль 19 км
тест, Тауйхабль 27 км
Тлюстен 60 км



Если поменять местами ключи и значения, то можно и словарь использовать.

@insolor, тогда зачем словарь? Мы же его словарность никак не используем ни в варианте ТС, ни в вашем.

Ну с практической точки зрения - да, незачем, а так - меньше скобочек будет)

Вот вам выбор через random.choice. 10 раз выбирается один вариант, чтобы показать, что случайный выбор есть. Ну, где-то получается подряд один и тот же два раза подряд, но всё же более-менее случайно.
from itertools import combinations
from random import choice

distances = {60:'Тлюстен 60 км', 52:'Тугургой 52 км', 36:'Казазов 36 км',
        50:'Красненский 50 км', 28:'Пчегатлукай 28 км', 30:'Адыгейск 30 км', 26:'Вочепший 26 км', 12:'Пшикуйхабль 12 км',
        10:'Нечерезии 10 км', 8:'Нешукай 8 км', 42:'Кунчукохабль 42 км, через аулы', 56:'Кунчукохабль 56 км через трассу',
        27:'Тауйхабль 27 км', 19:'Джиджихабль 19 км', 17:'Шевченко 17 км', 37:'Габукай 37 км', 4:'тест', 33:'тест'}

search_sum = 60 # тут вводим километры
variants = [comb for comb in combinations(distances, 2) if sum(comb) == search_sum]
for _ in range(10):
    choosen = choice(variants)
    print(distances[choosen[0]], distances[choosen[1]])

Пример вывода:
Тугургой 52 км Нешукай 8 км
Тауйхабль 27 км тест
Кунчукохабль 56 км через трассу тест
Тауйхабль 27 км тест
Тугургой 52 км Нешукай 8 км
Красненский 50 км Нечерезии 10 км
Тауйхабль 27 км тест
Тугургой 52 км Нешукай 8 км
Тугургой 52 км Нешукай 8 км
Кунчукохабль 56 км через трассу тест

Но учтите, что вы выбрали в качестве структуры данных словарь, ключ у вас дистанция. Вы не сможете записать в словарь два одинаковых ключа. Вам придётся это всё переделывать, если попадутся два одинаковых расстояния.
